# Google Maps' result off center

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I'm working on a map addition for a page, but the map is always off center with the given coordinates. An interesting extra bit of information that may be relevant is that the farther out (zoom out), the greater the discrepancy. I already did some research around other threads and I've found many that suggested using `map.getCenter()` but either that's not the solution or I have misused, seeing as it didn't work.

This is the code I'm using (shamelessly used the google maps tutorial):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng('lat', 'lng'),
          zoom: 20,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Since I'm creating the map on a `display:none` div, I'm also also using `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` in my page to fix the 'Top Left corner' bug. Note that my problem isn't about that but I read the misalignment can be caused by the resize solution, hence why I think it might be relevant.

Its very important that the map be on center given that I'm trying to reference a very small area. Where should I place the `map.getCenter()` or is there a better solution to this problem?

I appreciate any input given.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to preserve the original center while the map is resized, map center is set when `idle` event is fired.

**Example**

```js
function initialize() {
  var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(60.169621, 24.952265);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: centerLatLng,
      zoom: 19
  });


   google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function(event) {
       map.setCenter(centerLatLng); //force to set original center position 
   });

 

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
}
#map {
      height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How many decimal places are your lat and long values at? If zooming out increases the discrepancy, I'd think you need more exact float values (I often use 7 decimal places, which is what the Geocoding API provides).

Comment: On your suggestion I increased my decimals from 4 to 7 after getting a very centered view. I used base google maps for reference. Sadly it was still almost 100ft off center.